# awk ifs and variables - cannot pass a variable from one line towards subsequent lines

Tags: awk

First of all I'm new to awk so please excuse if it's something simple.

I'm trying to generate a file that contains paths. I'm using for this an `ls -LT` listing as well as an awk script:

This is an example of the input file:

```sh
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ cat structure-of-home.cnf

/home/:

vagrant

/home/vagrant:

postinstall.sh
```

This would be the expected output:

```
/home/vagrant
/home/vagrant/postinstall.sh
```

The awk script should do the following:

1. Check whether the line has a `:` in it
2. If yes  allocate the string (without `:`) to a variable (`$path` in my case)
3. If the line is empty print nothing
4. If it's not empty and it does not contain a `:` print the `$path` and then the current line `$0`

Here's the script:

```awk
BEGIN{
path=""
}
{
    if ($1 ~ /\:/)
        {
        sub(/\:/,"",$1)
        if (substr($1, length,1) ~ /\//)
            {
            path=$1;
            }
        else
            {
            path=$1"/"
            }
        }
    else if (length($0) == 0)
        {}
    else
        print $path$1
}
```

The problem is that when I run the script I get the following mess:

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ awk -f format_output.awk structure-of-home.cnf
vagrantvagrant
postinstall.shpostinstall.sh
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: You are pritning $path, this is error, just do: print path $1; (path without $ in front of it)

Comment: It is simple, but it's an easy mistake to make.  Note that, if `path` were equal to `3`, then `$path` would be `$3`.

Comment: What system are you on? My `ls` (`GNU coreutils 8.21`) doesn't support `ls -LT` since `-L` is `--dereference` & `-T` is `--tabsize` requiering a `cols` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197122/awk-ifs-and-variables-cannot-pass-a-variable-from-one-line-towards-subsequent#comment330624_197122) by [taliezin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102632/taliezin), your mistake was to use `$` to expand `path` when printing. Unlike `bash` or `make`, `awk` doesn't use the `$` to expand variables names to their value, but to refer to the fields of a line (similar to `perl`).

So just removing this will make your code work:

```awk
BEGIN{
path=""
}
{
    if ($1 ~ /\:/)
        {
        sub(/\:/,"",$1)
        if (substr($1, length,1) ~ /\//)
            {
            path=$1;
            }
        else
            {
            path=$1"/"
            }
        }
    else if (length($0) == 0)
        {}
    else
        print path$1
}
```

However, this is not really an `awk`ish solution:
First of all, there is no need to initialize `path` in a `BEGIN` rule, non-defined variables default to `""` or `0`, depending on context.

Also, any `awk` script consist of *patterns* and *actions*, the former stating *when*, the latter *what* to do.
You have one *action* that's always executed (empty *pattern*), and internally uses (nested) conditionals to decide what to do.

My solution would look like this:

```awk
# BEGIN is actually a pattern making the following rule run only once:
# That is, before any input is read.
BEGIN{
  # Split lines into chunks (fields) separated by ":".
  # This is done by setting the field separator (FS) variable accordingly:
# FS=":"  # this would split lines into fields by ":"

  # Additionally, if a field ends with "/",
  # we consider this part of the separator.
  # So fields should be split by a ":" that *might*
  # be predecessed by a "/".
  # This can be done using a regular expression (RE) FS:
  FS="/?:"  # "?" means "the previous character may occur 0 or 1 times"

  # When printing, we want to join the parts of the paths by "/".
  # That's the sole purpose of the output field separator (OFS) variable:
  OFS="/"
}

# First we want to identify records (i.e. in this [default] case: lines),
# that contain(ed) a ":".
# We can do that without any RE matching, since records are
# automatically split into fields separated by ":".
# So asking >>Does the current line contain a ":"?<< is now the same
# as asking >>Does the current record have more than 1 field?<<.
# Luckily (but not surprisingly), the number of fields (NF) variable
# keeps track of this:
NF>1{  # The follwoing action is run only if are >1 fields.

  # All we want to do in this case, is store everything up to the first ":",
  # without the potential final "/".
  # With our FS choice (see above), that's exactly the 1st field:
  path=$1
}

# The printing should be done only for non-empty lines not containing ":".
# In our case, that translates to a record that has neither 0 nor >1 fields:
NF==1{  # The following action is only run if there is exactly 1 field.

  # In this case, we want to print the path varible (no need for a "$" here)
  # followed by the current line, separated by a "/".
  # Since we defined the proper OFS, we can use "," to join output fields:
  print path,$1  # ($1==$0 since NF==1)
}
```

And that's all. Removing all the comments, shortening the variable name and moving the `[O]FS` definitions to command line arguments, all you have to write is:

```sh
awk -F'/?:' -vOFS=\/ 'NF>1{p=$1}NF==1{print p,$1}' structure-of-home.cnf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: '/:/{prefix=$1;next}/./{print prefix "/" $0}'
```

Note that is not a problem to have double `/` in path.
But if you'd you can add

```
awk -F: '/:/{sub("/$","",$1);prefix=$1;next}/./{print prefix "/" $0}'
```

or

```
awk -F: '/:/{prefix=$1;s="/";if(prefix~"/$")s="";next}/./{print prefix s $0}'
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  The question is not “How do I produce the desired output?”; the question is “What is wrong with my attempt at a solution?”  Yes, your answer *fixes* his problem, but your suggestions are so different from the OP’s that the absence of the `$` is very hard to perceive.  And you didn’t explain any of it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
awk 'match($0, "/*:$") {path = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1); next}
     NF {print path "/" $0}'
```